# Limit battery charging current and/or charging cutoff voltage in Android

Tags: android

Is there some API that could allow me to limit battery charging current and change voltage cutoff by software?

I have Motorola Moto G 2-gen. I want to extend battery life by using fast charging only when I need it.

I have two chargers now - one limited to 500mA and one fast. I want to reduce wires on my desk.

In my previous phone - Nokia N900 with Linux - it was possible, there was bq2415x charging controller and it had programmable charging current.

Comment: It's my personal experience. I was experimenting 3 years with my flashlight and Li-Ion and 4 high quality CGR16850 batteries. Batteries always charged with 0.2C current (0.5A charger) have higher capacity than batteries charged with 0.5C current.

Comment: Extending battery life can mean their service life, not capacity. It is much more likely that the two chargers had a different cut off voltage that meant one charged more than the other. Nothing to do with current.

Comment: I mean avaliable capacity after 2-3 years. Batteries wear out and loose capacity. Higher current (charge or discharge) - less cycles.

Comment: Voltage still has more to play in life that current: Higher cut off voltage, lower service life. If you want to preserve your battery, just do not fully charge. Source: http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/charging_lithium_ion_batteries

Comment: Yes, cutoff voltage is important too. I forgot to mention this in my question.

Comment: Lets delete this discussion. It is not related with programming. If you want to talk about batteries - please go to electronics.stackexchange.com.

Comment: It was related, there's not going to be an api for a useless feature. I was pointing out controlling current is useless.